# How to display a base64 image in a popover

Tags: javascript, base64

I've successfully displayed a base64 image on my webpage (a MS dynamics portal built on liquid templates) with this code, and then appending the element to a div:

```
imageElementCaseNote.src = 'data:image/png;base64, ${Picture}';
```

The issue I have is: how to the set the 'data-content' attribute of `imageElementCaseNote`, I tried the following, but get `[object HTMLImageElement]` instead of the image.

```
imageElementCaseNote.setAttribute('data-content', 'data:image/png;base64, ${Picture}');
```

What do I need to do to do? I think the data needs to be added as html but I can't work out how to do it.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There were two things I was missing, one obvious the other less so.

obvious: I needed to wrap the data in an image tag:

```
popImage = '<img src="' + imageElementCaseNote.src + '"/>';
ImageElementCaseNote.setAttribute('data-content', popImage);
```

less obvious: I needed to set the data-html attribute:

`imageElementCaseNote.setAttribute('data-html', 'true');`